# Pandas filling missing date values with a constant date

Tags: pandas, date, missing-data, imputation

I have a situation where I am trying to impute missing values in a date column using a standard date. I am using the follwing code but the missing values still remains as is and not getting replaced by the date I am using.

df:

```
termination_date
2020-06-28 00:00:00

2020-07-13 00:00:00
2020-08-11 00:00:00

2020-08-11 00:00:00
```

Now to replace the missing values, I want to use the date '2020-07-31 00:00:00' and I am using the following code:

```
df['termination_date'] = df['termination_date'].fillna(value=pd.to_datetime('2020-07-31 00:00:00'))
```

and the output should look like this :

```
termination_date
2020-06-28 00:00:00
2020-07-31 00:00:00
2020-07-13 00:00:00
2020-08-11 00:00:00
2020-07-31 00:00:00
2020-08-11 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to datetimes with non datetimes to `NaT`, so possible replacement by `fillna`:

```
df['termination_date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['termination_date'], errors='coerce')
                            .fillna(pd.to_datetime('2020-07-31')))

#because same times 00:00:00 are not shown
print (df)
  termination_date
0       2020-06-28
1       2020-07-31
2       2020-07-13
3       2020-08-11
4       2020-07-31
5       2020-08-11

print(df['termination_date'].tolist())
[Timestamp('2020-06-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-07-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-07-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-08-11 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2020-07-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-08-11 00:00:00')]

print (df.termination_date.dtypes)
datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'termination_date': ["2020-06-28 00:00:00",
...                                         "",
...                                         "2020-07-13 00:00:00",
...                                         "2020-08-11 00:00:00",
...                                         "",
...                                         "2020-08-11 00:00:00"]}, 
...                   index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> df
    termination_date
0   2020-06-28 00:00:00
1   
2   2020-07-13 00:00:00
3   2020-08-11 00:00:00
4   
5   2020-08-11 00:00:00
```

We can use a `loc` to replace the missing value by `pd.to_datetime('2020-07-31 00:00:00')` to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df.loc[df['termination_date'] == '', 'termination_date'] = pd.to_datetime('2020-07-31 00:00:00')
>>> df
    termination_date
0   2020-06-28 00:00:00
1   2020-07-31 00:00:00
2   2020-07-13 00:00:00
3   2020-08-11 00:00:00
4   2020-07-31 00:00:00
5   2020-08-11 00:00:00
```

To finish, we can convert the column in `Datetime` format to make sure that we don't have `string` values :

```py
df['termination_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['termination_date'])
```